# Use of the word "alternate"

Tags: word-usage

why it isn't "numbers alternate from right to left" instead? Isn't it start at the number 1 on the right side?[image]

Comment: You have a point, but the numbers do alternate between left and right.

Comment: I agree with WeatherVane. Possibly it would have been clearer if it had said, "Sometimes, rather than follow in series, the numbers are arranged as shown."

Comment: Got it, thank you so much, both of u.